# Как запускать .c файлы в Sublime Text 3 на Mac?

Tags: c, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Я собираюсь начать изучать язык C, я бы хотел в Sublime Text 3 на операционной системе Mac просто запускать .c файлы, чтобы можно было в консоли Sublime Text 3 смотреть результат работы программы. Как этого добиться?
GCC установлен

Comment: [Инструкция](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/set-up-compiler-for-c-for-sublime-text-3/26872).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Build system -> New build system...

Вставляете это:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lm", "-Wall"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell":false,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Всё.

Comment: Ну и да, Tools -> Build system и выбираете свою.

Comment: я ничего не понял, попытался так сделать, назвал при сохранении Build system compilec, а потом, когда я заново зашёл в build system, там это не появилось, но после нескольких отчаянных попыток у меня в этом меню почему-то появилось меню untitled, в итоге я забил, увидел пункт С Single File, выбрал его, нажал Command + B и у меня сработал вывод printf

Comment: Tools -> Build system -> New build system... Потом у вас должен создаться файл с `{ "shell_cmd": "make" }` Вместо этого содержимого вставляете вышеприведённые инструкции, сохраняете этот файл `[название].sublime-build`. Потом Tools -> Build system и выбираете [название].